# Initialize Plugin after $.load( has changed the DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, bind, live

I have something like this,

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    theme: 'light_square'
});
```

but then I use `$('.menu').click(function() { $('#content').load(page); });`

How do I initialize the plugin after the page has loaded so that it works with the new html that has been loaded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes a callback as the second parameter that fires when the page is loaded:

```
$('.menu').click(function() { 
    $('#content').load(page, function() {
        $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
                theme: 'light_square'
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jquery document.ready execute when the DOM is fully loaded

http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Example

```
$(function(){
  //Whatever code you want to execute after the page is loaded
})
```

If you want to have the function attached to elements you load to the DOM using ajax, you can use **live** or **on** based on your jquery version

If you use a jquery version less than 1.7, use **live**

```
$('.menu').live("click",function(){
 //Do whatever you want
});
```

If you use, jquery 1.7 or +, use, **on**

```
$('body').on("click",".menu",function(){
 //do whatever you want
});
```